# How to exclude a dependency defined in the pom.xml from a plugin defined in the same pom

Tags: maven, plugins, dependencies, pom.xml

I have a pom.xml in which I have a dependency defined as:

```
<dependency> 
            <groupId>abc.xyz.pig</groupId>
            <artifactId>pig</artifactId> 
            <version>10</version> 
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I want to define a new plugin in the same file, for which I need a higher version of the same dependency. How do I make my plugin use a higher version of the dependency and ignore the lower version defined above?

I tried adding the dependency of the newer version in my plugin definition like this, but it didn't work:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>my_plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>my_plugin_artifact</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.1</version>        
    <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>my_plugin_goal</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
    </executions>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>abc.xyz.pig</groupId>
          <artifactId>pig</artifactId>
          <version>11</version>
        </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Have you checked the change by `mvn -X ..`? Apart from that it sounds really strange to define a dependency as provided but having a plugin which needs that dependency as well but with a different version? Is the pom itself the Plugin pom or not?

Comment: Yes i checked it, it just shows that it downloaded and used the lower version. The pom has a lot of other stuff with other plugins, and I need to add mine to the existing framework.